# How change the scale and labels of key in openair::scatterPlot

Tags: r, scatter-plot, openair

I want to know how to control the key scale in scatterplot with 3 axis in the `openair` package.
When I make scatter plot, the key scale is randomly applied according to data. I want to fix the key scale to 0~100 % RH.

```
scatterPlot(data,
x="O3",y="SOC",z="RH",col="jet",linear="FALSE",cex=0.8,fontsize=35,
xlim=c(0,0.05),ylim=c(0,20),key.fooer = "RH(%)", xlab="O3 (ppm)",
ylab="SOC(ug/m3)",labelFontsize=13)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To force the graph, you can create pseudo data outside the limits and with HR = 0. For example:

```
data <- data.frame("O3"=c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.03), 
                   "SOC"=c(5, 3, 4, 2, 8), 
                   "RH"=c(100, 52, 75, 83, 63))
newdata <- rbind(data, data.frame("O3"=-1, "SOC"=-1, "RH"=0))
scatterPlot(newdata, x="O3",y="SOC",z="RH",col="jet",linear="FALSE",cex=0.8,fontsize=35,
            xlim=c(0,0.05),ylim=c(0,20),key.footer = "RH(%)", xlab="O3 (ppm)",
            ylab="SOC(ug/m3)",labelFontsize=13)
```

[image]